# \alsoaffiliation undefined control sequence with \documentclass{comjnl}

Tags: titles

I have a problem with `\documentclass{comjnl}`. I'm writing the first page and have a problem with authors labels. I have 4 authors, and **I would like two have to labels for the second and the third author (author, lab 1,2)**. Heres my `*.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{comjnl}

\title{Title}


\author{Author 1}
\affiliation{lab 1}
\alsoaffiliation{lab 2}

\author{Author 2}
\email{author@lab}

\author{Author 3}
\affiliation{lab 3}
\alsoaffiliation{lab 2}

\author{Author 4}
\affiliation{lab 2}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

I'm using Texmaker 3.4 on Xubuntu Linux and I get the 'Undefined control sequence' with `alsoaffiliation` command. Heres my `*.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.10.21)  22 DEC 2013 14:53
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test1.tex
(./test1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, po
lish, portuguese, loaded.
(./comjnl.cls
Document Class: comjnl 2009/07/27 v0.1c The Computer Journal class (DPC)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rotating/rotating.sty
Package: rotating 2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@r@tfl@t=\count88
\rotFPtop=\skip43
\rotFPbot=\skip44
\rot@float@box=\box26
\rot@mess@toks=\toks15
)
\c@affil=\count89
\c@remaffil=\count90
\absbox=\box27

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\thm@style=\toks16
\thm@bodyfont=\toks17
\thm@headfont=\toks18
\thm@notefont=\toks19
\thm@headpunct=\toks20
\thm@preskip=\skip45
\thm@postskip=\skip46
\thm@headsep=\skip47
\dth@everypar=\toks21
)
\c@definition=\count91
\c@lemma=\count92
\c@proposition=\count93
\c@corollary=\count94
\c@axiom=\count95
\c@remark=\count96
\c@example=\count97
\c@algorithm=\count98
\c@theorem=\count99
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rm on input line 468.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sf on input line 469.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \tt on input line 470.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bf on input line 471.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \it on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sl on input line 473.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sc on input line 474.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cal on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mit on input line 476.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/epsfig.sty
Package: epsfig 1999/02/16 v1.7a (e)psfig emulation (SPQR)
\epsfxsize=\dimen105
\epsfysize=\dimen106
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \alsoaffiliation
                    {lab 2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \alsoaffiliation{l
                      ab 2}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.15 \alsoaffiliation
                     {lab 2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \alsoaffiliation{l
                       ab 2}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

(./test1.aux)
\openout1 = `test1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 22.
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count100
\scratchdimen=\dimen107
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count101
\nofMParguments=\count102
\everyMPshowfont=\toks22
\MPscratchCnt=\count103
\MPscratchDim=\dimen108
\MPnumerator=\count104
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count105
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks23
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}


]
caffil>1
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 23.

Class cj Warning: No keywords.


Class cj Warning: No received date.


Class cj Warning: No accepted date.

[2


] (./test1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1885 strings out of 495009
 25574 string characters out of 3180581
 78556 words of memory out of 3000000
 5065 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 9184 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,8n,24p,242b,223s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10
.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb></
usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti7.pfb></usr/sha
re/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti9.pfb>
Output written on test1.pdf (2 pages, 49976 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 31 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 21 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: There is not any `\alsoaffiliation` command defined in `comjnl.sty`

Comment: @karlkoeller: so what can I use instead?

Comment: There is nothing similar in that document class. I'll try to see if a workaround is possible.

Comment: @karlkoeller: thanks, I would be very grateful!

Comment: @karlkoeller: have you came up with something? I dont really know how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, unfortunately not.

Comment: I believe that you should simply follow the instructions; add a note for the editors about your need and let them cope with the problem.

Comment: @mirx I'm not sure what you can get out of your bounty here: the class simply doesn't have the command you ask about. As egreg says, you really should stick to the 'rules' defined by the journal editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[To get this answered]

The document class does not define `\alsoaffiliation`. When submitting to a journal you should stick to the tools they provide. If you need something they don't provide, *ask the editorial office*. In the end they will do the final typesetting so it is best to do a minimum of modification of such classes.